# JavaScript Repetitive RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider my few input strings.

1. http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12/#/abcde/
2. http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12/#/abcde/!/fghij/
3. http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12/#/abcde/!/ghijk/!/klmno/

I have written this regex which works fine for input string 1.

```
(?:([a-zA-Z0-9.://_]*)(/#/(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)))

Output:
http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12/#/,http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12,/#/,abcde
```

But when I extend it to support repetitive **!/.../** place holder for input string 1,2 and 3, it doesn't work and gives empty string rather than token.

```
(?:([a-zA-Z0-9.://_]*)(/#/(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/))(!/(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/))*)

Output:
http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12/#/,http://local.app.com/local/frontend/v12,/#/,abcde,,
```

Answer (score 0):

?= captures in fact a position defined by what you specify after the ?=
It does not (also) capture whatever may match the specification of the lookaround (?=).

Try

(.+? # (/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}/) (!/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)* )

(hope I didn't make a typo, can't test it right now.)

This should capture the complete input, but the various captures inside give you access to the captured "tokens".

You can, in addition, give names to the various captures inside, making it easier to identify them in the match:

```
(.+?#(/(?<tokenFirst>[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)(!/(?<tokenMore>[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)*)
```

Success

Comment: It doesn't return all !/token/ parts but just the last one.

Comment: Because I also don't want slashes. In next comment, I have updated your regex.

Comment: (?:.+?#/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/(?:!/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)*)

Comment: I believe that in the named-variety that I suggested, you find the group "tokenFirst" capturing the first 'abcde' and in the 'tokenMore" group you find all the remaining "tokens"; I tested it, unless I've misread the output. (and they don't include the slashes). However, there are other captures in the regex give other parts of the total; it's a matter of just addressing the right groups in the match. Every () pair gives you a group/captures.

Comment: The token regex says "Invalid regular expression: /(.+?#(/(?<tokenFirst>[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)(!/(?<tokenMore>[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)*)/: Invalid group"

Comment: strange, I've tetsted it again. It may depend on de regex-variety (engine) and settings. I wanted to upload a picture (screenshot), but don't know how to do that (if it's possible at all). I'll try in the response section, rather than here as "comment".

Comment: As should be clear from earlier comments/posts: there are different regex engines. jsregex had, deviating from many others, the FORWARD slash as special character. Any special characters need to be escaped when they are to be used as literals. Therefore, the appropriate adjustment of the expression that I provided is simply to escape the forward slashes.

Comment: I didn't get it. You used slashes to escape characters? But I see this constant there and not for escaping.

Comment: No, I did NOT use a slash as escape character. However, in YOUR regex engine (jsregex), the (forward) slash is a special symbol. I wanted to use it as a literal. In any regex engine where it is a special character, you need to escape it whenever you want to use it as a literal. The escaping is done by prepending it by the escape character (usually the backslash). So, rather than only the '/', one has to put '\/' . This tells the regex engine that it must treat the forward slash as a literal (a character to find in the string). Google on "regex tutorial" and read up, it's easy. [closed]

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of my regextext, see comment]

Hope this will clarify my comment and earlier remarks.

Comment: I wrote your regex in jsFiddle so you may see the bug. http://jsfiddle.net/SVL9v/